# Problems with rewrite module and negation patterns

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

I have the following problem:

- If the url **contains** the keyword **"formulario-"** and it is a **http** connection, I want to redirect to the **https** version.
- If the url **doesn't contain** the keyword **"formulario-"** and it is a **https** connection, I want to redirecto to **http** version.

I tried the following .htaccess but it doens't work properly:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^formulario-(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but the general idea is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule formulario- https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !formulario-
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]
```

The theory being you cannot negate a `RewriteRule`, but you can negate a `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly does not work?

One thing that comes to mind is: Try using the [[L] flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for the first rule, so that apache stops to process the second rule, if the first rule applies.

I am not sure that's it though. You probably need some way to test whether the user was already redirected before.